# pygame error: video system has not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            running = False
```

This code right here is basic pygame code with window size, the main game loop, and event loop.

When I run this code, the pygame window opens and closes instantly. It gives me this error:

```
video system has not initialized, line 11, in <module> for event in pygame.event.get():
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your culprit is this line:

```
if event.type == pygame.quit():
```

Instead of checking for the `QUIT` event, you're calling the [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) function the first time your program enters the game loop, and the function uninitializes your `pygame` state, which then causes your game to crash the next time you try to access any `pygame` state.

What you want is to check if you got the `pygame.QUIT` event.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # this should be the event pygame.QUIT
        # and not the function pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Comment: Changing my code to this fixes the code stopping instantly, but now it gives me a new error called "Int object is not callable" and I cannot close the program without stopping it in the code editor.